# Pycharm python debugger cannot run files containing relative import

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, relative-import

I tried to mark as **Source root** the folder that contains the file to debug, but unsuccessful.

[Pycharm link]https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010615139-python-debugger-does-not-work-with-files-containing-relative-import

Below is my debug config:
[image]

I am using Pycharm 2021.1 (Porfessional Edition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Working directory dropdown to .../pythonProject. Now your working dir is timeserio/batches/chunked where there is no temeserio package inside it.